# Close specific file in Acrobat Reader via the command line

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, adobe-reader, tasks

I am working on something questionably useful (because better executions exist) which is a Sublime Text 3 PDFLaTeX build system with preview. I want to open files in Acrobat Reader, and so far all is good. But I need to be able to close these files too, or else they will be locked and PDFLaTeX won't be able to modify them and fail on rebuild. And I need to be able to do that from the command line.

I see no reason one couldn't do that, based on the fact that I can easily go into Task Manager and kill one of the subtasks labeled with filenames, which will close that file and that file only. [It looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGkdv.png)

However, I see no way to do this from cmd. `taskkill` doesn't seem to provide any option for that, but it looks like it should be possible.

Comment: Is the problem to "close specific file" or just "close current tab"? The second one can be done by sending Ctrl-W to Reader. Note: I don't get a separate process in Task Manager per each open file in Acrobat Reader.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The problem was to close a specific file, but thank you for mentioning that you can apparently send some sort of Ctrl+W signal to a process. Also thank you for mentioning that you do not get subprocesses for separate files in Task Manager. This is all very insightful. Regardless, I resolved to using Evince instead, although it isn't commonly used on Win10. Works like a charm, though!

Comment: You pdf file, the full path is known?

Comment: It is. Does that help?